# How to implement custom transtions in appcelerator ios

Tags: ios, appcelerator, transition, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to implement custom transitions,while switching from one window to another window please help me how to do this in appcelerator ios.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information on Appcelerator iOS transitions in this guide:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Animation-section-29004934_Animation-Transitions

The property you'd use is:

[Ti.UI.Window.transitionAnimation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-transitionAnimation)

You can find an example here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/transitionAnimationParam